# Can I change Mysql current time CURTIME() in query for testing purposes?

Tags: mysql

I have unit test, and I want CURTIME() always return same time, can I somehow do this ?

I can set timezone:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
SELECT CURTIME();
```

But is there any way to set time ?

Part of my query is:

```
(CURTIME() BETWEEN
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(opening_time, timezone, "UTC"))
AND TIME(CONVERT_TZ(closing_time, timezone, "UTC")))
```

I want to test for more timezones and different times

Comment: I doubt it. Why not use a static time string in the query you want to test?

Comment: I have :
(CURTIME() BETWEEN
                            TIME(CONVERT_TZ(opening_time, timezone, "UTC"))
                        AND TIME(CONVERT_TZ(closing_time, timezone, "UTC")))

Comment: Then use something like `'12:58:43'` instead of `curtime()`

Comment: You can recompile the source.

Answer (score 3):

CURTIME() is based on server timezone, thus the only way to make it change is directly changing the server timezone:

```
SET time_zone = 'France/Paris';
```

In debugging purposes, I would simply use @juergend idea to use a static time string to make your tests.

EDIT: didn't read well, you already knew that part. Still, I don't understand why you don't use a static time string in your query, no matter how many times you have to do it in the query

```
 ('12:34:56' BETWEEN TIME(CONVERT_TZ(opening_time, timezone, "UTC")) AND TIME(CONVERT_TZ(closing_time, timezone, "UTC")))
```